# W/BluetoothAdapter(25289): getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, android-bluetooth

I am developing an app using dart and flutter,

the app is about printing out some strings  using a mobile Bluetooth printer (Honeywell RP4)

i used many packages from pub.dev and usually i get the mentioned error above in title,

i tried to write native code in java file inside flutter project and this is my code:

```
package com.example.java_flutter_printer;

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import android.content.Intent;
// import android.support.annotation.WorkerThread;
// import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
// Import neccessor namespace
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import  android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import  android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;
import android.os.Handler;

import java.util.concurrent.RunnableFuture;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {

    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
    BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;

    OutputStream outputStream;
    InputStream inputStream;
    Thread thread;

    byte[] readBuffer;
    int readBufferPosition;
    volatile boolean stopWorker;

    // TextView lblPrinterName;
    // EditText textBox;

    private static final String CHANNEL = "samples.flutter.dev/PricePrinter";
    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
    new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
        .setMethodCallHandler(
        (call, result) -> {
            // This method is invoked on the main thread.
            if (call.method.equals("printLabel")) {
                int prtResult = connect();
                System.out.println("prtResult is: " + prtResult );
            
                if (prtResult != -1) {
                result.success("true");
                } else {
                result.error("UNAVAILABLE", "printer not available.", null);
                }
            } else {
                result.notImplemented();
            }
        }
        );
  }

  private int print() {
    int printResult = -1;
    System.out.println("insdide print function of java");
    printResult = 1;
    return printResult;
  }

  public int connect(){
    try{
        FindBluetoothDevice();
        openBluetoothPrinter();
        printData();
        // disconnectBT();
        return 1;
    }catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    }
  }

  void FindBluetoothDevice(){
    System.out.println("inside FindBluetoothDevice fun()");
    try{
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if(bluetoothAdapter==null){
            System.out.println("No Bluetooth Adapter found");
        }
        if(!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
            Intent enableBT = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBT,0);
        }
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if(pairedDevice.size()>0){
            for(BluetoothDevice pairedDev:pairedDevice){
                if(pairedDev.getAddress().equals("00:10:20:D9:A7:7F")){
                    System.out.println("hello hello" + pairedDev.getAddress());
                    bluetoothDevice=pairedDev;
                    System.out.println("Bluetooth Printer Attached: "+pairedDev.getName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("inside FindBluetoothDevice exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

  void openBluetoothPrinter() throws IOException {
    try{
        //Standard uuid from string //
    UUID uuidSting = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
    
    if (bluetoothDevice != null) {
        bluetoothSocket=bluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuidSting);
        bluetoothSocket.connect();
        outputStream=bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
        inputStream=bluetoothSocket.getInputStream();


        beginListenData();
    } else {
        System.out.println("bluetoothDevice is null");
    }

    }catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println("inside openBluetoothPrinter exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  void beginListenData(){
    System.out.println("inside beginListenData func()");
    try{

        final Handler handler =new Handler();
        final byte delimiter=10;
        stopWorker =false;
        readBufferPosition=0;
        readBuffer = new byte[1024];
        thread=new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("inside first Thread");
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker){
                    try{
                        int byteAvailable = inputStream.available();
                        if(byteAvailable>0){
                            byte[] packetByte = new byte[byteAvailable];
                            inputStream.read(packetByte);
                            for(int i=0; i<byteAvailable; i++){
                                byte b = packetByte[i];
                                if(b==delimiter){
                                    byte[] encodedByte = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                    System.arraycopy(
                                            readBuffer,0,
                                            encodedByte,0,
                                            encodedByte.length
                                    );
                                    final String data = new String(encodedByte,"US-ASCII");
                                    readBufferPosition=0;
                                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            System.out.println("inside run inside run inside beginListenData fun()");
                                            // lblPrinterName.setText(data);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }else{
                                    readBuffer[readBufferPosition++]=b;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }catch(Exception ex){
                        stopWorker=true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println("inside beginListenData exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

void printData() {
    System.out.println("inside printData fun()");
    try{
        String msg = "hello from the other side";
        msg+="\n";
        outputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
        System.out.println("Printing Text...");
    }catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// Disconnect Printer //
void disconnectBT() throws IOException{
    try {
        stopWorker=true;
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
        bluetoothSocket.close();
        System.out.println("Printer Disconnected.");
    }catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

now when i reach `bluetoothSocket.connect();` line inside `openBluetoothPrinter()` function
the error `W/BluetoothAdapter(25289): getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback` show up again

now please tell me what am I missing? what should I do to make my printer prints out any string

expecting the printer to print out some text